# Need explanation of reading and writing of wchar_t* to binary file

Tags: c, binary, fwrite, fread

can someone explain me what is a proper way to write wchar_t* string to binary file and then read it back(using fread/fwrite)?

here is what i have (its working)

```
struct someStruct{
    int someint;
    wchar_t* data;
    int someint2;
}
someStruct s;
s.someint = 111;
s.data = L"blah blah .... lets say 1-1000 characters long";
s.someint2 = 222;

//writing
FILE * f = _wfopen(L"myfile",L"wb");
fwrite(&(s.someint), sizeof(int), 1, f);
fwrite(&(s.data), sizeof(wchar*), 1, f);
fwrite(&(s.someint2), sizeof(int), 1, f);
fclose(f);

//reading
FILE * f2 = _wfopen(L"myfile",L"rb");
fread(&(s2.someint), sizeof(int), 1, f2);
fread(&(s2.data), sizeof(wchar*), 1, f2);
fread(&(s2.someint2), sizeof(int), 1, f2);
fclose(f2);
```

everything is working, values are properly loaded. **the question is what should be the second parameter of fread and fwrite in this specific example**, why is it working with e.g. 4(which is sizeof(wchar_t*)) or 20 and causing buffer overrun with 150, these values vary based on data length,

EDIT: these are what i have been using (was working last time i checked it :P 1 year ago):

```
wchar_t* loadStrFromFile(FILE* file) {
    int strLen;
    fread(&(strLen), sizeof(int), 1, file);
    wchar_t* result = new wchar_t[strLen];
    fread(result, strLen, sizeof(wchar_t), file);
    return result;
}

void saveStrToFile(const wchar_t*& data, FILE* file) {
    int strLen = wcslen(data)+1;
    fwrite(&strLen, sizeof(int), 1, file);
    fwrite(data, strLen, sizeof(wchar_t), file);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this example is, well, it would take me a long time to enumerate everything that's wrong with it.

Comment: If this is C++, as you say it is, then why don't you use `std::wstring` and persist it using streams? And if you want a C answer, then please re-tag.

Comment: Writing a pointer value to a file is *never* correct.  Write another program that reads the file to see this for yourself.

Comment: @Hans: It could be correct if the value is read back in and used only during the same execution of the same program.  But yes, "never" is close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is particularly wrong:

```
fwrite(&(s.data), sizeof(wchar*), 1, f);
```

This would only write sizeof(wchar*) = 4 or 8 bytes.

Oh yes, and you probably don't want to write a pointer. Missed that one.

If you want to write an actual string data (assuming you're on Windows):

```
size_t len = wcslen(s.data); //get the number of characters
fwrite(s.data, sizeof(wchar_t), len, f);
```

Comment: Since this writes a pointer, it doesn't really matter how much of the pointer is written does it?

Comment: yep, my bad, being inattentive.

Comment: damn, nothing is working :P, i have tried every possible combination like fwrite(s.data, len, 1, f); fwrite(s.data, len*sizeof(wchar_t), etc. etc. , nothing is working in my glorious code :P

Comment: s.data is a wchar_t - you need `fwrite(s.data, len, sizeof(wchar_t), f);`. This is, of course, assuming you want to just dump the wide characters to a file, so you can read them back again. A more conventional approach might be to convert them to a standard encoded text format, so that other programs could read them too.

Comment: @Nikki Locke , so what about reading, first i am writing to file length of string, then actual string data, i can read int length correctly but not string, can't i just use fread(s.data, loaded_len, sizeof(wchar_t), f); - its not working

Comment: s.data is a pointer - you must make it point to some memory somewhere to put the data in. This is where it gets complicated - you can use malloc or new to allocate the memory (but you must then keep track of it and delete it when no longer needed). I take it using strings (so this is all taken care of for you) is out of the question?